# создал базу данных в sql и выдаёт ошибку ORA-00907: missing right parantesis

Tags: mysql

вот где выдаёт ошибку , подскажите проблему

```
CREATE TABLE Cameri
(
    CodCamera INT PRIMARY KEY (1,1),
    Confort varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
    Camera varchar2(50),
    NumarPersoane varchar2(50),
    Pret INT NOT NULL,
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE Cazare
(
    Id  PRIMARY KEY (1,1),
    CodCazare  NOT NULL,
    DataCazarii date,
    DataPlecarii date,
    CodClient INT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    CodNumarului INT NOT NULL,
    Pret INT NOT NULL,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите использовать MySQL, то на мой взгляд, выражения должны быть такими:

```
CREATE TABLE Cameri
(
    CodCamera INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Confort varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Camera varchar(50),
    NumarPersoane varchar(50),
    Pret INT NOT NULL
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE Cazare
(
    Id  INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    CodCazare INT NOT NULL,
    DataCazarii date,
    DataPlecarii date,
    CodClient INT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    CodNumarului INT NOT NULL,
    Pret INT NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Вот такую ошибку выдаёт :ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_200200", line 626 ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658 ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_200200", line 612 ORA-06512: at "APEX_200200.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 1749

Comment: Это новая ошибка? В новом месте?

Comment: Та же ошибка, только полностью

Answer (score 0):

Английским по белому написано - отсутствует правая скобка.

А по делу, у вас лишние запятые в конце перечисления полей (см ответ выше)

Comment: Удалил лишние скобки, ошибка не ушла